# wget, webservice and SOAP

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wget

I am a newbie trying to test a webservice with wget to get a better understanding of how it works.

At the moment, I have a bash script looking like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

REQUEST="<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns2=\"http://schema.thecompany.se/header/v1\" xmlns:ns3=\"http://messages.thecompany.se/theServicePath/theService/v1\"><S:Body><ns3:theRequest><ns2:identity>1234567</ns2:identity></ns3:theRequest></S:Body></S:Envelope>"

MY_FILE="/tmp/myfile.xml"
echo $REQUEST > $MY_FILE

/usr/bin/wget -O - --no-cache -dv --http-user="theDomain\theUser" --http-password="aPassword" \
        --post-file=$MY_FILE \
        --header="SOAPAction: \"http://xmlns.thecompany.com/path/theService/theRequest\"" \
        --header="Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8;" \
        --auth-no-challenge \
        --no-check-certificate \
        https://service.thecompany.com/path/theServicePath/theService_v1.svc/basic
```

From what I have read, the SOAPAction field is mandatory for SOAP over HTTP but may be "" since the HTTP request URI already provides the intent of the SOAP message.

Is this the recommended way, to have SOAPAction: "" instead of supplying the URI at two places as I have done?

If the SOAPAction is fully specified, is my code above wrong? Should the SOAPAction URI be the same as the HTTP request URI?

In examples I have seen, the list of namespaces (xmlns:) are more than what are in use in the request. E.g. I have often seen xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" but never use of ns3 in the request. Why is that done?

Also, I can't get the script to work. After the requested is posted, the response is 403 FORBIDDEN.

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain what is actually **not** working with your script, but I may have spotted a typo in the `--http-user` option argument: you did not escape the backslash. Can you try with `--http-user="theDomain\\theUser"` ?

Comment: The problem with the script is that when the request is posted, the response is 403 FORBIDDEN. Adding a backslash doesn't help. My main concern though is to get an understanding for the questions above :-)